# Loading Batch Offline Data to DWH environment with Kafka as the "Entering door"

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, hdfs, bigdata

Some context to my question.
As you can see here:
[image: Airbnb Data Infra]
https://medium.com/airbnb-engineering/data-infrastructure-at-airbnb-8adfb34f169c

There are 2 "doors" to load data into HDFS

1. Sqoop
2. Kafka

Using this topology as an example, what will be the best practice to load batch offline data which is hosted on an FTP server info HDFS?

Let's also assume that no changes are needed to perform on the file, we need to store it in HDFS in the same structure it is stored in the FTP server.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka isn't exactly configured to transfer "file sized" data by default. At least, not entire files in one message. Maybe break the lines apart, but then you need to reorder them and put them back together in HDFS.

In my experience, I've seen a few options from an FTP server.

Vanilla Hadoop, no extra software required

- Use an NFS Gateway,  WebHDFS or HttpFS to copy files directly to HDFS as if it were another filesystem

Additional Software required

- Your own code with an FTP and HDFS client connection
- Spark Streaming w/ an FTP Connector and HDFS write output
- Kafka & Kafka Connect with an FTP Connector source and HDFS Sink
- A Flume agent running on the FTP Server with an HDFS sink
- Apache NiFi with a GetFTP and PutHDFS processor
- Streamsets Data Collector doing something similar to NiFi (don't know the terms for this one)

> we need to store it in HDFS in the same structure it is stored in the FTP server.

If these are small files, you're better off at least compressing the files into a Hadoop supported archive format before uploading to HDFS